# Clojure: Error: Could not find or load main class test.core.main

Tags: clojure

I just want to build a simple "hello world" in clojure and compile it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anybody tell me why i am getting this error, when trying to execute the jar:

[image]

Comment: Please use code blocks rather than screenshots for code snippets. It is more difficult for people to help you as they can't easily reproduce your problem. See here for a guide using Markdown: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by accident:

1. I just should reference, where the main method is, but not the method itself.
2. I forgot the gen-class
3. I think, i should call the "main" "-main"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. The :main argument to b/uber identifies a namespace, not a function. For your main function to be executable by java -jar you need both (:gen-class) -- to generate a Java-style class from the Clojure namespace -- and -main for the function name (so it compiles to a Java method, not a Clojure function). - is the default prefix for such things but can be configured via options to :gen-class in ns.